# Load different version(Java1.4 and Java1.5) of JAR in server start time

Tags: java

Actually I have two different version of JAR like java1.4 and java1.5. I need both but at runtime means when my server start I want to load the specific type of JAR. Please give me some code to resolve this issue. I am using WebSphere Application Server 6.1

Comment: You're a member since 2 months but probably dont know how stackoverflow works. Accept some of the answers given to your previous 5 questions, people will be more inclined to help you. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's about classloading in WebSphere.
There are options in WebSphere administration about the order in which the classes are loaded at startup. 
You can choose to load the JAR inside your archive before those belonging to the parent (the app server is the parent)
Called "parent first" or "Child first"

Answer (score 0):

Each version of WebSphere requires a particular JRE version, you cannot vary the JRE WebSphere itself uses. By default WebSphere makes many standard Java classes available to all applications, these include things such as Web Service runtime and XML parsers and so on.

So if you need to vary the JVM itself (say from 1.5 to 1.4) you're out of luck.

However if you need to  override some of extension classes you can include the relevent JAR files in your application's EAR. Explore the "Parent First / Parent Last" setting on your application.

IF the classes you want to use are at a higher version of Java (eg. Java 6) then again you're out of luck.

If I understand correctly you have single cell, with some WAS 6.0 and some WAS 6.1? And you app is deployed to servers at both levels. (I view this is a pretty risky thing to do - so much complexity.)  You can create WebSphere Shared Libraries. Create two such libraries, one for the 1.4 JAR and one for the 1.5. You can assign Shared Libraries either to Applications or to Servers. In your case you should assign each library to the appropriate server.

Comment: I have two different version of JAR like JAR1 and JAR2 for WAS6.0(java 1.4) and WAS6.1(java 1.5). AT run time I need one of them but both are needed because 4 servers are running on WAS6.1 amd other server are running on WAS6.0. So when I run the WAS6.0 then I need JAR1 and when I run the WAS6.1 then I need JAR2. Please help me to overcome from the issue.